# How can I convert the date field in aggregate response to a different timezone?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying aggregation from elasticsearch like below. There is a date type field `timestampUtc` in the document which saves the utc time. In the query, I am using an input parameter with an offset like `2022-06-01T00:00:00+10:00` and use  `calendar_interval` to support the different timezone. I believe Elasticsearch converts the time `2022-06-01T00:00:00+10:00` into utc time internally when compare with the value saved in the document.

```json
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "timestampUtc": {
                  "gte": "2022-06-01T00:00:00+10:00",
                  "lte": "2022-07-05T23:59:59+10:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "value": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestampUtc",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The response from above query is:

```json
   "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2022-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1653955200000,
          "doc_count" : 897,
          "amount" : {
            "value" : 4.3873789E7
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1654041600000,
          "doc_count" : 1395,
          "amount" : {
            "value" : 5.6002755E7
          }
        },
```

As you can see that in `key_as_string` field, it shows utc format which is from the value saved in the db. The question is how I can make the date format in the response same as the one I put in the query.